# How to get the following join query

Tags: sql, oracle, join

How to get the following join

input:

```
table1:     table2:
col1        Col1   col2 col3
A           A        1    2 
B           B        4    5
C
```

output:

```
col1   col2 col3 
A       1     2
B       4     5
c       -     -
```

Comment: Please specify properly what columns do you have in table 1 and table 2.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I think you should search google for `SQL JOIN`.

Comment: ... specifically for an outer join

Comment: This should be googled first. Or at least show some code snippets or something that indicates an effort from your side. You are not supposed to ask people to do your work on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.col1, t2.col2, t2.col3
  FROM table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.col1=t2.col1
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `full outer join`:

```
select coalesce(t1.col1, t2.col1), t2.col2, t2.col3
from table1 t1 full outer join
     table2 t2
     on t1.col1 = t2.col1;
```

This returns all rows from both tables, even those that don't match (it is a left and right outer join at the same time).

You can also do this using `union all` and aggregation:

```
select col1, max(col2) as col2, max(col3) as col3
from ((select col1, NULL as col2, NULL as col3
       from table1
      ) union all
      (select col1, col2, col3
       from table2
      )
     ) t
group by col1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.col1, t2.col2, t2.col3
from table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2
on t1.col1 = t2.col1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this if you wan't the '-'

```
SELECT t1.col1, coalesce(t2.col2,'-') as col2, coalesce(t2.col3,'-') as col3
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.col1=t2.col1
```

Answer (score 0):

See my sqlfiddle

```
create table table1(
    col1 char(1)
  );

insert into table1 values('A');
insert into table1 values('B');
insert into table1 values('C');


create table table2(
    col1 char(1),
    col2 int,
    col3 int
  );

insert into table2 values('A',1,2);
insert into table2 values('B',4,5);


select 
  t1.col1, 
  coalesce(t2.col2,'-'), 
  coalesce(t2.col3,'-')
from 
  table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.col1=t2.col1
;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc768/2

Answer (score 0):

You need to do an outer join

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table1 t1,
       table2 t2
WHERE t1.col1 = t2.col1(+)
```